# when the situation to use default router occurs

Tags: networking

It is said that we use default router when an IP address doesn't match any other routes in the routing table. Usually for a network a routing table set for all entries. So we route through these routers. But usually network setting is done in a well established manner, so what is the situation to use default router? when it occurs?

Comment: A routing table almost never contains "all" entries. Yes, it may in a Private network but never for the public internet. Your routing table would be astronomically huge if that were the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A default route is used to find addresses when a router does not "know" where another public or private IP address resides. A default route is calculated using supernetting with the default route of 0.0.0.0 which means, anything that matches any address with numbers 0-255.0-255.0-255.0-255 and is unknown by the router or not in its routing table is forwarded to another gateway router.

The hope is that the next hop gateway or default route will "know" where the IP address resides.

In home routing, a default route in your home router is usually set to your ISP's router or gateway.